# Find and Replace Formula Needed in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a big problem with replacing data in an Excel-sheet. There are more that 6000 keyword and more that 300000 rows in the main sheet. I have to replace those keywords in the next row of the original text row. I am trying this formula:

```
Sub ReplaceExample()

Dim OriginalText As String
Dim CorrectedText As String

OriginalText = Range("A2").Value
CorrectedText = Replace(OriginalText, "left", "Left")
CorrectedText = Replace(OriginalText, "limited", "Limited")


Range("A2").Offset(, 1).Value = CorrectedText 
End Sub
```

But I am having a problem with `Range()`.
I have a huge data range in the Excel-sheet.

Can I use a single formula for all those replacements???

For Example: this is a sample data for original text cell Number (A2:A12)

```
00-00 Buick Lesabre (limited) headlight Set;
00-00 Buick Lesabre Tail Light left;
00-00 Buick Lesabre Tail Light Pair;
00-00 Buick lesabre tail Light Right;
00-00 Buick Lesabre Tail Light Set;
00-00 Dodge /Plymouth Neon Fog Light Pair;
00-00 Dodge caravan/Plymouth voyager/ Chrysler towncar(W/ Quad) Headlight Left;
00-00 Dodge Caravan/voyager /Towncar(W/O Quad&Dtrl)Headlight Set;
00-00 Dodge/Plymouth Neon Fog Light Left;
00-00 Dodge/Plymouth Neon Fog Light Right;
2000 Nissian 350z;
```

Keywords cell number (A2:A8)

```
Limited;
Left;
Lesabre;
Caravan;
Voyager;
350Z;
Towncar
```

I need to solve it quickly.

Comment: Does it have to be a VBA solution? Why not just use Control F to perform find/replace?

Comment: then he'd have to do that 6000 times right?

Comment: You are going to have to incorporate .FindNext and .Replace to accomplish this. Start with the code found on this site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196143%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

do this:

insert 2 columns at the beginning, in A column put all keywords. in b columns put all replacements. start at the top in the first row. then use this macro:

```
Sub macro1()


    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = thisWorkbook.Activesheet.Range("A1")'uses thisWorkbook and Activesheet such that this macro will work regardless of the name of the sheet or workbook.
    While rng.FormulaR1C1 <> "" 'processes untill a blank cell is encountered
        Cells.Replace What:=rng.FormulaR1C1, Replacement:=rng.Offset(0, 1), LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
    Wend

End Sub
```

you'll want to paste this macro in the same module as the one you already have underneath your current macro. Alternatively you can simply delete everything between `Sub ReplaceExample()` and `end sub` in your macro, and copy everything in my example between `Sub macro1()` and `end sub` and paste it where your code was.

Comment: change the `Range("A1").Activate` to A2 if you need.

Comment: You should avoid the use of `.Activate` or `ActiveCell` since it could lead to instabilities and will slow the process.  **[This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/2687063)** describes some solutions about this matter.

Comment: you're right and normally I'd totally avoid that. But I don't think OP is ever going to look at the again after today, and Im pretty sure it's not some in depth function we're building here, so if they stick `application.screenupdating = false` at the beginning it should run fine for what they need.

Comment: You should always post code that is at the best of your knowledge, you cannot imply OP's use of your code.  Moreover, this is a learning site therefore, you should always show best practices in your answers.  I think that the code you posted would be a code that someone who know programming would write for a quick tool because he or she knows the potential consequences of using this structure, so it should not be aimed at someone who's learning.

Comment: +1 if you explicitly define `Range("A1")` (i.e.: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheet("Sheet1").Range...` or `Me.Range...` or else) and that you explain where to paste this macro in-line with your definition of `Range("A1")`

Comment: determined to make a teacher out of me yet eh? editz complete :P